# Is it necessary to deploy a CloudKit container to production?

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

I use CoreData with CloudKit for an app that is already available on the App Store. So far I did not publish my development container to production - I recently spotted the hint "This container has not been deployed to Production" in the CloudKit dashboard.

I did not call `initializeCloudKitSchema` during development yet either... all entities are created "adhoc" and everything works fine - also in production.

Did I get it right, that deploying a container/schema to production manually and before publishing a new release to the App Store is just necessary when you for example rely on pre-filled entities or maybe that certain entities are available right away?

Would it cause any problems, if I'd puslish the current schema subsequently?